# Prevent packages from being removed after doing `dpkg --set-selections`

Tags: apt, package-management

Im trying to install all the packages installed on the other host.

- From host = Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- To host = Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I've ran `dpkg --get-selections > packages.txt` on the 'old'-system. To import them to the newer system i've ran: `dpkg --set-selections < packages.txt`. This seems to be working fine.

But when I try to install them; `apt-get` tells me it wants to remove the following packages:

```
 e2fsprogs libblkid1 (due to e2fsprogs) libuuid1 (due to e2fsprogs) util-linux (due to e2fsprogs) hostname mount libmount1 (due to mount) acpid adduser aptitude console-setup cron dmsetup dselect e2fsprogs eject grub-common
  grub-gfxpayload-lists grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common hostname ifupdown initramfs-tools
  initscripts kbd keyboard-configuration libblkid1 libdevmapper1.02.1 libmount1 libuuid1 libxapian22
  linux-image-3.2.0-49-virtual linux-image-virtual linux-virtual module-init-tools mount mountall
  netbase ntpdate openssh-client openssh-server passwd plymouth procps resolvconf rsync rsyslog
  tasksel tasksel-data ubuntu-minimal udev upstart ureadahead util-linux
```

The problem is; I see a couple of 'required' packages that I don't want to deinstall/remove. Is there a command like `apt-get upgrade --only-install`? Or is there a work-around to only INSTALL the packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way was parsing the output of `--get-selections` before importing the list. Now to correct the situation some workarounds should be applied:

On 'old' system:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v 'deinstall` > packages.txt
```

This will get you a list of only the packages installed. Now in the target system:

```
sudo dpkg --clear-selections
sudo dpkg --set-selections < packages.txt
```

Now lets fix the mess of the previous command:

Save the following to some file, lets call it `packages.fix`;

```
e2fsprogs install 
libblkid1 install 
libuuid1 install 
util-linux install 
hostname install 
mount install 
libmount1 install 
acpid install 
adduser install 
aptitude install 
console-setup install 
cron install 
dmsetup install 
dselect install 
e2fsprogs install 
eject install 
grub-common install 
grub-gfxpayload-lists install 
grub-pc install 
grub-pc-bin install 
grub2-common install 
hostname install 
ifupdown install 
initramfs-tools install 
initscripts install 
kbd install 
keyboard-configuration install 
libblkid1 install 
libdevmapper1.02.1 install 
libmount1 install 
libuuid1 install 
libxapian22 install 
linux-image-3.2.0-49-virtual install 
linux-image-virtual install 
linux-virtual install 
module-init-tools install 
mount install 
mountall install 
netbase install 
ntpdate install 
openssh-client install 
openssh-server install 
passwd install 
plymouth install 
procps install 
resolvconf install 
rsync install 
rsyslog install 
tasksel install 
tasksel-data install 
ubuntu-minimal install 
udev install 
upstart install 
ureadahead install 
util-linux install
```

Now lets do `sudo dpkg --set-selections < packages.fix` continue with your operation, it should be fine now.